# the internal angle, and the sum of the internal angles in any N-sided polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

We have:

triangles have $3\times 60°=180°$

squares have $4\times 90°=360°$

pentagon have $5\times 108°= 540°$

hexagons have $6\times 120°=720°$

heptagons have $7\times 128.57° = 899.99 = 900°$

octagons have $8\times 135°=1080°$

What is the sum of the internal angles $\Pi$ in any $N$-sided polygons?

What is the value of one of the angle $\alpha$ in any $N$-sided polygons?

What is the value of $\Pi/\alpha$ in any $N$-sided polygons?

what is the value of $(\Pi-\alpha)/\alpha$ in any $N$-sided polygons?

i can draw the geometry.
[image: $N$-sided polygons]

Comment: the answer to the first is Π=(n−2)⋅180∘ and the answer to the third is Π/α=N² but there is something between the both.

Comment: Hi you have changed the question . $\alpha$ is external angle . you did not mention it previously .

Comment: Note : external angle = $ 360^{\circ} -internal angle $

Comment: i gave you a point to help me asking the question. It isn't coming from a book.

Comment: Even you did not mention $\Pi $ is an internal angle and $\alpha $ is an external angle . Any way after knowing internal angle formula its easy to go further .

Comment: Then you came after an hour and changed question as per your convenience .So keep this question as such and open a new thread for whatever new question you have in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mbox{sum of internal angles of polygon with $N$ sides } =  (N-2) * \pi $$

from which you can deduce the rest

$$\mbox{each internal angle $\alpha$} =  \frac{(N-2) * \pi}{N} $$

$$ \pi/\alpha  =  \frac{N}{N-2} $$

$$ \frac{\pi - \alpha}{\alpha}  = \frac{2}{N-2} $$

$$ \frac{sum\ of\ internal\ angles}{each\ angle\ \alpha} = N $$ 
$$ \frac{sum\ of\ internal\ angles - each\ angle\ \alpha}{each\ angle\ \alpha} = N -1 $$ 
where '$N$' is the number of sides of polygon and

$\pi = 180^{\circ}$

Note: in your question you have used  $\Pi$ to denote something. both cases if it denotes $180 ^{\circ} $ or if it denotes sum of internal angles , have been solved in my answer . I don't want to use $\Pi$ again (as i have already used it to denote $180 ^{\circ} $ ) and confuse readers . Hope this helps .

Comment: @Daniel Rust . Thanks for the edit . I was searching for this degree symbol .But what does "circ" in \circ means . Is it circle ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's standard for degrees but it's the usual symbol used for function composition (eg $f\circ g (x)=f(g(x))$) and it works well as an index to be a degree symbol. The circ refers to circle yes.

Comment: thanks for edit. for example for (π−α)/α i have π=7 * 128.57° = 899.99 = 900° and (π−α)/α=7*771,43/128,57 =42

Comment: @user52413 , what are u suggesting ?

Comment: α=((N−2)∗π)/N but π is not factor of N

Comment: Why should $\pi$ be a factor of N ? $\alpha $ can be a fraction(so decimals ).

Comment: as $\alpha$ is an angle . $\pi$ is also expected to be in degrees. $\pi$ is  $180^{\circ} $ here . . N is the number of sides . Hope this helps .

Comment: it is a difficult question, i am sorry if you expected something else. the idea is to have the square or triangle in the same number of degres but to understand how it is possible to change the value of all polygones to have something with the external angle.

Comment: external angle = $ 360^{\circ} -internal angle $

Comment: yes but the sum of externale angle are not always the same result, it isn't the internale angle who give always (3N−6)∗60°. and i don't know if 60° is true because it is maybe proportional to the externale angle.